# Splitting field of $x^{n} - a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $a > 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

My professor gave me this problem to do and I just wanted to check whether I'm on the right track or not. I want to find the splitting field of $x^{n} - a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $a$ is a positive rational number. I also want to find the degree of the splitting field. Here is what I've tried

Lets first try finding the roots of this polynomial

$$x^n -a= 0$$
$$x^n = a$$

This implies that $x = a^{\frac{1}{n}}, a^{\frac{1}{n}}\omega,...,a^{\frac{1}{n}}\omega^{n-1}$ where $\omega = e^\frac{2\pi i}{n}$.

A field where the polynomial splits would be $\mathbb{Q}[a^{\frac{1}{n}}, a^{\frac{1}{n}}\omega,...,a^{\frac{1}{n}}\omega^{n-1}]$, but the splitting field needs to be the smallest field where the polynomial splits. So I think that we would only need $\mathbb{Q}[a^\frac{1}{n}, \omega]$ to get all of the roots. I think this is the splitting field for the polynomial but I'm unsure how to prove it.

Now in order to calculate the degree of this extension I tried the following

$[\mathbb{Q}[a^\frac{1}{n}, \omega]:\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}[a^\frac{1}{n}, \omega]:\mathbb{Q}[\omega]]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}[\omega]:\mathbb{Q}]$

I think that

$[\mathbb{Q}[a^\frac{1}{n}, \omega]:\mathbb{Q}[\omega]] = n$

because you would need all of the powers of $a^\frac{1}{n}$

$[\mathbb{Q}[\omega]:\mathbb{Q}] = \phi(n)$

Here $\phi(n)$ is the euler totient function. So I think that the degree would of the splitting field would end up being $n*\phi(n)$.

I had a few questions. First thing I wanted to know whether the splitting field that I have is correct and if it is then how you would prove it. I also wanted to know whether the degree of the splitting field is correct.

==================================================================
Edit: I don't think that $\mathbb{Q}[a^\frac{1}{n}, \omega]$ will be a splitting field in the case that $a^\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$. For example if we have $n = 2$ and $a = 4$ then the splitting field of $x^2 -4$ should just be $\mathbb{Q}$, but I'm wondering whether what I did above works if $a^\frac{1}{n} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Is $n$ prime?  For instance, $\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi\mathrm{i}/6} = 1 + \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi\mathrm{i}/3}$, so something that looks like a 6th root of $1$ can be generated with a 3rd root.

Comment: $n$ is just a natural number.

Comment: @EricTowers If $n$ was prime is there a general splitting field for polynomials of the form $x^{n} - a$

Comment: The splitting field is contained in $\mathbb{Q}[a^{1/n},\omega]$ since $x^n-a$ splits there. On the other hand, if $x^n-a$ splits in a field $F$, then $a^{1/n}\in F$ and since $a^{1/n}\omega\in F$, we also have $\omega=a^{1/n}\omega/a^{1/n}\in F$. Therefore, $F\supset \mathbb{Q}[a^{1/n},\omega]$. There is no problem with $a^{1/n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, since then $\mathbb{Q}[a^{1/n},\omega]=\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$. The case $x^2-4$  is, like all others, not a problem, $\mathbb{Q}[2,-1]=\mathbb{Q}$. The degree of the extension is what has problems.

Comment: @pompelle Just wondering wouldn't the formula for the degree be off since $2*\phi(2) = 2$ but if you you look at $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the degree should just be 1. Since $x^2 -4 = (x+2)(x-2)$  and both of the roots are in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Yes, the degree is not correct. It is true that it is a multiple of $\phi(n)$, since $[\mathbb{Q}[\omega],\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n)$, but the factor $[\mathbb{Q}[a^{1/n},\omega]:\mathbb{Q}[\omega]]$ is not necessarily $n$. For example, for $x^{12}-m^{12}3^{6}$ the degree is just $\phi(12)$, since $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, and therefore $(m^{12}3^6)^{1/12}\in\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, in that case, for all positive rational $m$.